# React to Flask API call resulting in requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError

Tags: javascript, python, flask, fetch-api

I'm building a react app that calls a simple Flask API. I've tested my flask API using curl and python's requests module. The API returns the desired result. However, when I try calling the Flask API within my react app using fetch, there is a ChunkedEncodingError.

I know my API is being hit by my fetch request because I see a 500 error on my Flask server log.

```
    with requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), stream=True) as r:
        for line in r.iter_lines():
            if line:
                resp_obj = json.loads(line)
                if "response" in resp_obj:
                    result_text += resp_obj["response"]
    return result_text
```

I believe the iter_lines function is causing the issue, and here it is in the code. How can I fix this?